# .htaccess allow both www and non-www

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have subdomain that can be accessed like `https://sub.example.com` but if I do `www.sub.example.com` it returns

> Server Not Found

Currently **without any `.htaccess` file**  if I type `sub.example.com` it goes to `https://sub.example.com` I want the same thing happen if I type `www.sub.example.com`

**Any idea?**

Comment: "Server Not Found" - this is a DNS issue.

Comment: @MrWhite The DNS were set by cloudflare for `non-www` and for `www` I've added it myself, based on my hosting CS for subdomains to redirect `www` to `non-www` either I've had to buy separate SSL for my subdomain or use cloudflare rules option which I chose the second one and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

---

---

OR if every request has to be `https` and without `www` then better we could try.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: would you mind explain it a bit? I'm not so sure about `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: and also i think all your redirected links are include `www` i don't want `www` in my urls just `https://sub.example.com`

Comment: @mafortis, sorry if I got it wrong. So you want every URL to go to https? Could you please confirm once?

Comment: @mafortis, could you please check my edited solution and let me know on same, please make sure you are clearing cache before testing this one.

Comment: I've tested with proxy website still didn't work, however I've done rules by cloudflare and that fixed it :D, I'm going to accept your answer while I'm not sure if it's 100% correct but here i leave [article reference](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/3212384-how-to-redirect-domain-to-another-domain-without-hosting-plan) of cloudflare rules for others as well. Thank you

Comment: @mafortis, thank you for nice gesture here. I would like to request you to please do add your solution additionally with mine one too, lets keep both so that it helps future users cheers :) and happy learning.

Comment: "cloudflare" - this should have been stated in the question. "Server not found" is a DNS/Cloudflare issue. The request is not even reaching the server, so any amount of `.htaccess`/mod_rewrite wizardry is not going to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

**The best solution for this would be like this:**

```
# Add www if not subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Remove www if subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Example of how it would come out:

- http://website.com/abc
- http://www.website.com/abc
- http://sub.website.com/abc
- https://sub.website.com/abc
- https://www.website.com/abc
- https://website.com/abc